# Substract previous row from preceding row by group python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame

```
  ID  Date 
   1  2020-07-09
   1  2020-07-11
   1  2020-07-21
   2  2020-07-04
   2  2020-07-09
   2  2020-07-18
```

I want to subtract each row in the date column by the row above it BY each ID group.

Excepted output

```
    ID  Date        Days 
    1  2020-07-09   0
    1  2020-07-11   2
    1  2020-07-21   10
    2  2020-07-04   0
    2  2020-07-09   5
    2  2020-07-18   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df["Days"] =(df['Date']-df.groupby('ID')['Date'].shift()).dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

output of df:

```
   ID   Date        Days
0   1   2020-07-09  0
1   1   2020-07-11  2
2   1   2020-07-21  10
3   2   2020-07-04  0
4   2   2020-07-09  5
5   2   2020-07-18  9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Days"] = df.groupby("ID")["Date"].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID       Date  Days
0   1 2020-07-09     0
1   1 2020-07-11     2
2   1 2020-07-21    10
3   2 2020-07-04     0
4   2 2020-07-09     5
5   2 2020-07-18     9
```